# Firebase - updateChildValues crashes app when setting key in dictionary from constant

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

All I am trying to accomplish is setting the user's email string as a key in my database. My issue seems to be that the updateChildValues method crashes whenever I set the dictionary using a key that I have assigned to a constant - In this case userEmail. If I change the key to a string literal it works just fine, but that is not how I intend to structure this database node.

```
guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid, let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email else {
            // handle
            return
        }

        let groupId = UUID().uuidString
        let userGroupIdValue = ["groupId": groupId]
        let groupName = ["groupName": text]
        let userEmail = [email: 1]

Database.database().reference().child("groups").child(groupId).child("memberEmails").updateChildValues(userEmail, withCompletionBlock: { (error, reference) in

                   // handle errors

                })
```

If I change the userEmail dictionary to ["someText": 1] it works just fine, as do the constants userGroupIdValue and groupName. Through my troubleshooting, it seems as though this method does not like the fact that the email property in Auth.auth().currentUser? was previously an optional, even though I am using a guard statement. I have used if let statements to unwrap as well and it still crashes. Could this be a bug of sorts?

Comment: Add quotes to the key

let userEmail = ["email" : 1]

Comment: is `email` inside `[email: 1]` a constant?

Comment: Yes, it is a constant.

Comment: I've tried string interpolation, casting the dictionary as [AnyHashable: Any], everything I can think of. The only thing in the console after the crash is: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well firebase support got back to me and it seems the issue is the email address that was unwrapped contained a "." in the string, and this character is not allowed to be used in a key in the database along with several other characters. Super frustrating but at least I have an answer.